# How to implode array elements, skipping first N elements?

Tags: php, arrays

My case is simple: I have an array of texts. I need to use first 2 of them as parameters, and then implode all the rest to a string, to create third parameter. I cannot know how many elements there will be.

- I don't like copying whole array and deleting $array[0] and $array[1], as it may be a pretty big one and it seems unneeded.
- I cannot delete values from original array, as I need them for future use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foo($array[0], $array[1], join(',', array_slice($array, 2)))
```